# Как для вывода в консоль отключить ограничение на ширину выводимых данных?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

DataFrame иногда не отображается полностью, если столбцов слишком много или они слишком широкие.

Как отключить это ограничение на ширину выводимых данных?

Comment: См. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51593236/3832970

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Это сделано для того, чтобы обезопасить вас, т.к. вывод огромных таблиц на экран может занимать очень много времени.

[Сделать это можно так](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html#getting-and-setting-options):

```
with pd.option_context("display.max_rows", None, "display.max_columns", None):
    print(df)
```